# Pixel art in XAML for Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'd like to create a game for Windows Phone. To ease the development process, it'd be great if I could use XAML to create the UI rather than creating my own UI framework. But the game shouldn't look like an app. I'd prefer it to be somewhat pixel-art-ish. So I had to make the xaml page e. g. 200px in width and scale it up without interpolation. I'd be great to disable anti-alaising as well.

Is that (at least in parts) possible?

And please don't say something like "you shouldn't do that, because it looks ugly". It looks ugly for apps, but games should be something different.

Comment: So what's wrong with vectors?

Comment: It's just something different. I like vector art as well, but some games just require this old retro-graphics style, so using pixel art is the only way to get in the right mood. Another reason: pixel art is just the art style which can be created very fast:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create bitmaps from scratch using `WriteableBitmap` which will ease that part.
As for scaling up, you can always scale XAML elements using `RenderTransform`.

Comment: But again, that would mean I had to handle all the events myself. Does that mean there is no built-in way to do this. If so, I'd prefer XNA (or Monogame) for performance reasons.

Comment: What do you mean that you need to handle all the events yourself? Who else will handle them? And built-in way for what? Pixel art? There is none, but by pixeling it yourself and scaling up you get exactly what you want - scaled up XAML with pixels.

Comment: I wanted to know if I could archive it with pure xaml, so it wouldn't be nessecary to do all that low-level stuff and simply add an eventhandler to a button. In case that isn't possible, the answer would just be "no"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the UIRenderer’s texture to the screen in your `GameTimer.Draw` event handler, you could render it into another smaller texture, then render that smaller texture to the screen using nearest filtering (untested code below):

```
SamplerState ss = new SamplerState();
ss.Filter = TextureFilter.Point;
ss.AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Clamp;
ss.AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Clamp;
ss.AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Clamp;
Matrix transformMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale( new Vector3( scaleX, scaleY, 1 ) );
spriteBatch.Begin( SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, ss, null, null, null, transformMatrix );
spriteBatch.Draw( smallerTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White );
spriteBatch.End();
```

Here the smallerTexture is the smaller texture to which where you’ve rendered the UIElementRenderer’s texture.
Main downside here resource overhead — you first producing the screen-size texture. I do not know whether it is a showstopper or not, you should test on a low-end hardware device.

Another way is pass the smaller texture size in the UIElementRenderer’s constructor and then rendering this smaller texture as shown in the code above. However, this method breaks touch input coordinates, which I do not know how to fix.